# Building a nested form with a many-to-many relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a model (User) that `has_many` of another model (Profession) - and this is supposed to be represented by one (or multiple) select menu in a form.

I cannot get my head around why the select menu doesn't get rendered? Am I constructing the select helper in the wrong way? Or is something else wrong in the view or the controller? The `name` attribute of the User is showing up alright in the form.

---

The models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :professions, through: :occupations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :occupations
end

class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occupations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :occupations
end

class Occupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profession
end
```

The controller:

```
def edit
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, ocuppations_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :profession_id])
  end
```

The view (compressed):

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :occupations do |builder|  %>
    <%= builder.select :profession_id, Profession.all.collect {|x| [x.title, x.id]} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be a collection select?

```
<%= builder.collection_select(:profession_id, Profession.all, :id, :title) %>
```

Comment: It could be, that it should be a collection select instead. But it still doesn't show up :( 
Should I do some kind of preparation to the object in the Controller (or elsewhere)?